# How to download all attachments from outlook using python?

Tags: python-3.x, email, outlook

Problem :

In one mail i will be having multiple attachments and i need to download all.

How can i do this?

My code:

```
import win32com.client
import os
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case the inbox. You can change that number to reference
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
subject = message.Subject
#
get_path = 'C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\resumes'

for m in messages:
    if m.Subject == "FW: Opportunity with Mindtree | Automotive Infotainment |":

        print (message)
        attachments = message.Attachments
        attachment = attachments.Item(1)
        attachment.SaveASFile(os.path.join(get_path,attachment.FileName)) #Saves to the attachment to current folder
        print (attachment)
        message = messages.GetNext()

    else:
        message = messages.GetNext()
```

Answer (score 4):

There are other issues with your code, but this should allow you to get multiple attachments:

```
import win32com.client
import os
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case the inbox. You can change that number to reference
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
subject = message.Subject
#
get_path = 'C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\resumes'

for m in messages:
    if m.Subject == "FW: Opportunity with Mindtree | Automotive Infotainment |":

        print (message)
        attachments = message.Attachments
        num_attach = len([x for x in attachments]))
            for x in range(1, num_attach):
            attachment = attachments.Item(x)
            attachment.SaveASFile(os.path.join(get_path,attachment.FileName))
        print (attachment)
        message = messages.GetNext()

    else:
        message = messages.GetNext()
```

Comment: MS Outlook list indices are 1-based, so it should be: `for x in range(1, num_attach+1)`

Comment: If I want to get attachment from a folder that user created?

Answer (score 1):

```
import win32com.client
import os
import datetime as dt

mydesktop = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/Desktop/'
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

print (dt.datetime.now())

# setup range for outlook to search emails (so we don't go through the entire inbox)
lastWeekDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 4)
lastWeekDateTime = lastWeekDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')

# Select main Inbox
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

# Optional:  Select main Inbox, look in subfolder "Test"
#inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["Test"]

messages = inbox.Items

# Only search emails in the time range above:
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastWeekDateTime +"'")

print ('Reading Inbox, including Inbox Subfolders...')

# Download a select attachment ---------------------------------------
# Create a folder to capture attachments.
Myfolder = mydesktop + 'Outlook Export/'
if not os.path.exists(Myfolder): os.makedirs(Myfolder)

try:
    for message in list(messages):
        try:
            s = message.sender
            s = str(s)
            print('Sender:' , message.sender)
            for att in message.Attachments:
                # Give each attachment a path and filename
                outfile_name1 = Myfolder + att.FileName
                # save file 
                att.SaveASFile(outfile_name1)
                print('Saved file:', outfile_name1)

        except Exception as e:
            print("type error: " + str(e))
            x=1

except Exception as e:
    print("type error: " + str(e))
    x=1

#Delete unused file types (like .png)-----------------------------------------

test = os.listdir(Myfolder)

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".png"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(Myfolder, item))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32com.client
import os

def outlook_download():
    global final_file_Downloaded
    
    outlook = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    item_count =inbox.Items.Count
    messages=inbox.Items
    messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
    outputDir = os.getcwd()
    ext = '*.xlsx'
    for message in messages:
        if message.Subject == 'FW: Organic Twitter File':
            attachments = message.Attachments
            m_attach = len([i for i in attachments])
            for i in range(1, m_attach):
                attachment = attachments.Item(i)
                if (attachment.FileName).endswith('xlsx'):       
                        attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(outputDir,
attachment.FileName))
                    print("Twitter file has been downloaded",attachment.FileName )
               
outlook_download()
```

Comment: Code-only answer  are discouraged; please explain your answer and the rationale for some decisions you made (the global variables and hardcoded constants are unnerving).